# PHP regex to replace content between { }

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex to replace everything between `[[` and `]]` with a callback function. Somehow I don't know how to change it to replace the text between single curly braces `{ }`:

```
preg_replace_callback('~\[\[((?>[^]]++|](?!]))*)]]~', function ($m) use ($that) {
    return "REPLACE TEXT"; }, $layout);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace_callback('~\{((?>[^}]++)*)\}~', function ($m) use ($that) {
return "REPLACE TEXT"; }, $layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting an answer that should work with nested brackets also:

```
$str = 'this is the text that {i want{to} replace this text} from it';
echo preg_replace('/ \{ ( (?: [^{}]* | (?0) )+ ) \} /x', 'REPLACE TEXT', $str);
//=> this is the text that REPLACE TEXT from it
```

This regex is using [**conditional subpattern regex**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php).